# what is the default working directory for adb push/pull and how do I change it?

Tags: android, adb

I pulled out a file from the android sdcard using adb and it seems it goes to `c:\documents and settings\userName` by default. I don't know how it got set to this folder since this is not where adb is installed, but probably has got something to do with the fact that both the `workspace` and `.android` folders are located here. How do I change this default location for pull command of adb?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The default directory for `adb pull` or `adb push` seems to be the current directory (aka `.` ).
If you issue a command such as the following, not specifying the `target` directory

```
adb pull /boot.txt
```

the file (provided it exists) will be copied to the current directory.

**Windows users:**

Take notice of the following: If you are using Windows (Vista or newer), chances are that if the current directory requires elevated privileges to write on, Windows will silently replicate the directory structure of your current directory in a special folder called `VirtualStore` and will copy your files in it.

The full path for `VirtualStore` is: `%LOCALAPPDATA%\VirtualStore`, which most likely will translate into `C:\Users\<account_name>\AppData\Local\VirtualStore`.

So, in the following scenario,

```
C:\> cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyCustomADBInstallLocation"
C:\Program Files (x86)\MyCustomADBInstallLocation> adb pull /boot.txt
```

your file `boot.txt` will end up in this folder

```
C:\Users\<account_name>\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\MyCustomADBInstallLocation\
```

Comment: thanks. v interesting. My stuff ended up in C:\Users\\[user]\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\

Comment: And how to change this current directory?

Answer (score 6):

you can mention the `destination` location for `adb push/pull`, see example:-

> adb push a.txt /data/local
>
> adb pull /data/local/a.txt .

`.` means present directory.

or

> adb pull /data/local/a.txt C:\

Hope this helps.

Comment: `adb pull /data/local/a.txt C:\ ` doesn't work. Pull works only to default directory

Comment: what is the error you are getting when you specify local dir? There is nothing like pull works only to default directory. From adb help- `adb pull [-a] <remote>... <local>`. See example-  `C:\>adb pull /sdcard/b C:\work\
[100%] /sdcard/b`

Comment: Yep, just tried it and it worked. However, not for root directory (`C:\ ` or `D:\ `), only if I specify 2nd-level+ dir. You should edit your answer accrodingly.

Answer (score 0):

i'm using linux, and noticed that if i opened the terminal as root, its opened @ home. when i pull items, it dumps to that repository, meaning to my "home" directory. will try opening terminal in a different folder and running adb pull from there to see if that makes the files dump to the folder terminal is opened in.

Comment: what was the result after your experiment?