# how to transfer files to android one using ubuntu 14.04

Tags: android, file-transfer, ubuntu-14.04, usb-drive

by default andriod let us transer file copy and paste windows/mac.
i cannot paste/paste file in Spice Android One Dream UNO Mi-498.
i am using ubuntu 14.04
and yes gmtp does not work
reffering to 
 [this blog on gmtp](http://www.humans-enabled.com/2011/12/how-to-fix-samsung-galaxy-nexus-mtp.html)
and
[this is how its done on mac or windows](https://www.android.com/filetransfer/)

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 014: ID 18d1:4ee1 Google Inc. Nexus 4

$ lsusb -v


Bus 002 Device 014: ID 18d1:4ee1 Google Inc. Nexus 4 //hey,but my manufacturer is spice 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x18d1 Google Inc. //i wonder how device id belongs to LG nexus 4?
  idProduct          0x4ee1 Nexus 4
  bcdDevice            2.16
  iManufacturer           2 Spice       // this is my mobile manufacturer
  iProduct                3 Spice Mi-498
  iSerial                 4 Mi498HA14090139
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           39
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           3
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              5 MTP
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x001c  1x 28 bytes
        bInterval               6
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered
```

Comment: Although not intended for end users, ADB has file push/pull commands.

Comment: @ChrisStratton i way looking for a more gui .

Comment: There actually is one in the DDMS tool, but the command line is far more powerful.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html this seems usefull and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18372427/what-is-the-default-working-directory-for-adb-push-pull-and-how-do-i-change-it

Comment: @ChrisStratton  my phone manufacturer is different than one listed in device ids which belongs to google nexus from LG

Comment: You can still use the same mechanism.  Almost every Android device supports ADB, it's just more or less of a pain to set it up.

Answer (score 1):

Try the AirDroid app. Download it [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid&hl=pt_BR)!
You connect to your phone via browser, then you can transfer from/to your computer.

Hope it helps =]

Comment: When you see a question that does not relate to programming, please vote to close it as off topic, or flag if you don't have the closing prerogative yet. By the way… you live in CGD. What a coincidence!

Comment: @arthursfreire  AirDroid currently only works if the computer and Android device are connected to the same WiFi network which in my case not with wifi either,this does not work with usb.

Comment: @DavidCesarino - the question may very well relate to support of development needs, but it is true that this answer does not.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Maybe, but I just thought configuring Ubuntu in order to proper move files to/from device (as a user, as it seems) would be better suited for SuperUser or, probably, Android Enthusiasts. At least that was my impression.